# Glimpse icon does not appear

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I'm trying to use Glimpse for MVC 4. My issue is that, although I have followed the [installation instructions on the Glimpse site](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Installation), the Glimpse icon does not appear on my site.

Basically I created a new MVC 4 project and added NuGet package Glimpse.MVC4. Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <!-- If you are having issues with Glimpse, please include this. It will help us figure out whats going on. -->
      <logging level="Trace" />
  </glimpse>
</configuration>
```

When I run my site, I navigate to `http://localhost:12345/glimpse.axd` and click the `Turn On Glimpse` button, which looks to create a cookie on my site (which I see via Chrome developer toolbar). When I navigate back to `http://12345` I do not see any icon appear in the bottom right of the page, as described in the instructions.

I've looked at various StackOverflow questions about this scenario, but a lot mention the old `/Glimpse/Config` way of doing things. As I've not done anything out of the ordinary, I'm wondering whether I've just missed a step?

EDIT:

Huh, I hadn't noticed I'd turned on the logging. OK, now things are clearer:

```
2013-04-02 21:42:09.5624 | DEBUG | get_Binders method of type 'System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker' is not proxyable. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.5624 | DEBUG | set_Binders method of type 'System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker' is not proxyable. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.5624 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6064 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6064 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6064 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6064 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6064 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6364 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6364 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IUnvalidatedValueProvider'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6364 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6364 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IUnvalidatedValueProvider'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:09.6504 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:10.0504 | DEBUG | Methods inspected via proxy generation hook on type 'System.Web.Mvc.IView'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:10.0504 | INFO | Replaced IView of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView', named 'Index', with proxy implementation. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:10.2524 | WARN | Unable to locate '</body>' with content encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)'. Response may be compressed. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:13.6916 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:15.0587 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:17.4918 | INFO | Replaced IView of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView', named 'Index', with proxy implementation. | 
    2013-04-02 21:42:17.4918 | WARN | Unable to locate '</body>' with content encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)'. Response may be compressed. |
```

Comment: It looks like you have logging turned on. Can you share the contents of the log file that is being created? (It should be in your site's root, called Glimpse.log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was simply missing a `<body>` tag in the HTML. The icon appears once I added the missing tag.